# Do you have documents on SonarLint for Visual studio except details provided on Sonarlint site

Tags: sonarlint

Do you have documents on SonarLint for Visual studio except details provided on Sonarlint site

Comment: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/SonarLint+for+Visual+Studio

Comment: Could you tell us if you are looking to something in particular?

Comment: We are facing challenges in binding sonar projects within VS 2015 post running analysis through command line using sonar scanner. Below is the error message.                                                                                    "Failed to bind the solution to SonarQube project, try again"